# Python pySerial read data from arduino breaks when sending "(char)0"

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I send some data from an arduino using pySerial.

My Data looks like

```
bytearray(DST, SRC, STATUS, TYPE, CHANNEL, DATA..., SIZEOFDATA)
```

where sizeofData is a test that all bytes are received.

The problem is, every time when a byte is zero, my python program just stops reading there:

```
serial_port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
while serial_port.isOpen():
  response_header_str = serial_port.readline()
  format = '>';
  format += ('B'*len(response_header_str));
  response_header = struct.unpack(format, response_header_str)
  pprint(response_header)
serial_port.close()
```

For example, when I send `bytearray(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)` everything is fine. But when I send something like `bytearray(1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)` I don't see everything beginning with the zero.

The problem is that I cannot avoid sending zeros as I am just sending the "memory dump" e.g. when I send a float value, there might be zero bytes.

how can I tell pyserial not to ignore zero bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the source of PySerial and the problem is in PySerial's implementation of `FileLike.readline` (in http://svn.code.sf.net/p/pyserial/code/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialutil.py).  The offending function is:

```
def readline(self, size=None, eol=LF):
    """\
    Read a line which is terminated with end-of-line (eol) character
    ('\n' by default) or until timeout.
    """
    leneol = len(eol)
    line = bytearray()
    while True:
        c = self.read(1)
        if c:
            line += c
            if line[-leneol:] == eol:
                break
            if size is not None and len(line) >= size:
                break
        else:
            break
    return bytes(line)
```

With the obvious problem being the `if c:` line.  When `c == b'\x00'` this evaluates to false, and the routine breaks out of the read loop.  The easiest thing to do would be to reimplement this yourself as something like:

```
def readline(port, size=None, eol="\n"):
    """\
    Read a line which is terminated with end-of-line (eol) character
    ('\n' by default) or until timeout.
    """
    leneol = len(eol)
    line = bytearray()
    while True:
        line += port.read(1)
        if line[-leneol:] == eol:
            break
        if size is not None and len(line) >= size:
            break
    return bytes(line)
```

To clarify from your comments, this is a replacement for the `Serial.readline` method that will consume null-bytes and add them to the returned string until it hits the `eol` character, which we define here as `"\n"`.

An example of using the new method, with a file-object substituted for the socket:

```
>>> # Create some example data terminated by a newline containing nulls.
>>> handle = open("test.dat", "wb")
>>> handle.write(b"hell\x00o, w\x00rld\n")
>>> handle.close()
>>>
>>> # Use our readline method to read it back in.
>>> handle = open("test.dat", "rb") 
>>> readline(handle)
'hell\x00o, w\x00rld\n'
```

Hopefully this makes a little more sense.

Comment: but when I change the character to another one, I just shifted the problem to another bit-sequence...

Comment: Change the character?  The function I posted will happily read b'\x00' and append it to the byte array.  There is no need to modify the output from your Arduino, only the way you read from the serial port in Python.

Comment: yeah, but "\n" has a byte representation also. So I shift the problem only to this representation which is 10 in decimal.

Comment: One of us isn't quite understanding the other here.  There was a slight typo in my solution (I referred to LF which is a constant defined within `PySerial` as equal to `\n`, I've changed this to `\n` in my code).  I've also updated my solution with a representative example (switching the serial port for a file handle, but it's functionally the same).

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now.  The easiest thing to do would be to change how you send the data entirely.  Compute the length of the data you're going to send on your Arduino and send that first (packed as a 16-bit integer).  Then, allocate a buffer that size in your Python script and read in exactly that amount of data.